# Hybrid graphics driver not working (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, hybrid-graphics

After two days of intensive research and two Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 installations later I've reached a dead end.

I currently own a [HP dv6-3315ep](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02697555) laptop, which comes with a 6550M graphics card, and the Intel graphics card for lower power consumption (switch-able graphics).

I've read everywhere how to install the AMD drivers manually, which I've done in all different ways, including different versions due to the how-to posts being dated and new driver versions being available, and also tried installing the drivers to the additional drivers directly from Ubuntu, with that being said I've either ended in Low Graphics (after running aticonfig --initial -f) mode or using the default drivers from the clean install (because not forcing aticonfig --inital would come out as not detecting anything related to any usable AMD hardware).

Before installing fglrx, I've `lspci | grep VGA` and what I've got from it was

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]`

what made me realize that it would seem like it was not detecting my graphics card correctly, but I didn't mind it.

So, I wish to know if there is any reliable method that I could use to correctly install AMD proprietary drivers on my computer, or only install the Intel graphics driver so it would allow me to use the HDMI and VGA ports on my computer.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right this is a muxed hybrid system. In my opinion; here is the problem : 
1) The "recent" catalyst driver don't support muxed system...
2) The "old but not to old "catalyst driver  support muxed graphics system but not recent kernel nor Xorg server. It cause the installation to failed.
And Unfortunately I was not able to determine precisely the driver version for which it support muxed system.

So a further investigation would be : 
-Find the version for which muxed system was supported. 
-Then find a combinaison of Kernel/xorg ( hopefully jut a good version of Ubuntu) compatible with this driver.
Personally, I gave up since I want to use recent kernel/xorg....
The starting point is wiki.cchtml.com but it didn't led me too far.